# Arduino code intermittent

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, relay, rtc

Have an alarm for "tea time", "lunch time" and "tea time". Works well at times but occasionally it gets stuck on the alarm not resetting, other times it does not trigger the alarm.
please help I am new to Arduino and all of this.
here is the code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <ThreeWire.h>  
#include <RtcDS1302.h>

ThreeWire myWire(4,5,2); // IO, SCLK, CE
RtcDS1302<ThreeWire> Rtc(myWire);
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3f,16,2);
int Relay = 7;

void setup () 
{
    //RtcDateTime compiled = RtcDateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__);
    //Rtc.SetDateTime(compiled);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lcd.init();
    lcd.backlight();
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("  ClearChoice");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(" Installations");
    delay(5000);
    lcd.clear();
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(8, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
}
void Alarm()
{
    digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH); 

    delay(3000);
    
    digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);  
}
  
void AlarmActive()
{
    RtcDateTime now = Rtc.GetDateTime();
    int MySec = now.Second();
    int MyMin=now.Minute();
    int MyHour=now.Hour();
    int MyDay=now.DayOfWeek();
   
    
    if(MyHour==10 && MyMin==00 && MySec==00 && MyDay<=5)
    {
        Alarm();
    }
    if(MyHour==10 && MyMin==15 && MySec==00 && MyDay<=5)
    {
        Alarm();
    }
    if(MyHour==12 && MyMin==00 && MySec==00 && MyDay<=5)
    {
        Alarm();
    }
    if(MyHour==12 && MyMin==30 && MySec==00 && MyDay<=5)
    {
        Alarm();
    }
    if(MyHour==15 && MyMin==00 && MySec==00 && MyDay<=5)
    {
        Alarm();
    }
    if(MyHour==15 && MyMin==15 && MySec==00 && MyDay<=5)
    {
        Alarm();   
    }
}
  

void Clock()
{
    RtcDateTime now = Rtc.GetDateTime();
    int dayOfWeek = now.DayOfWeek();
    String days[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    
    
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    char buffer[3];
    lcd.print("Date: ");
    lcd.print(now.Day());
    lcd.print("/");
    lcd.print(now.Month());
    lcd.print("/");
    lcd.print(now.Year());
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Time: ");
    sprintf(buffer, "%02d", now.Hour());
    lcd.print(buffer);
    lcd.print(":");
    sprintf(buffer, "%02d", now.Minute());
    lcd.print(buffer);
    lcd.print(":");
    sprintf(buffer, "%02d", now.Second());
    lcd.print(buffer);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    
    Serial.print("Time: ");
    Serial.print(now.Hour());
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(now.Minute());
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(now.Second());
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Date: ");
    Serial.print(now.Day());
    Serial.print("/");
    Serial.print(now.Month());
    Serial.print("/");
    Serial.print(now.Year());
    Serial.println();
    lcd.print("Time: ");
    Serial.println(days[dayOfWeek]);
    Serial.println();
    AlarmActive();
    
    delay(1000);      
}

void loop () 
{   
   Clock();      
}
```

Comment: Please try delaying only for like half a second instead of a full second in `Clock()`. Currently you are probably occasionally missing the relevant second of an alarm.

Comment: Thank you. Will give it a try.

Comment: Also, `Alarm()` has a 3-second delay. This can contribute to the issue you are seeing, as @chrisl mentioned. Check out an example called "blink without delay". That should give me some idea about how NOT to use delay.

Comment: Thank you. 
Fahad

Comment: What do you see on the serial monitor when the program fails to work as expected?

Comment: @Fahad: You changed the code while reformatting it. Maybe you should explain to the OP that the empty `else` statements have no effect at all and can be removed.

Comment: forget the seconds ... trigger the alarm on day, hour, minute ... insert a 60 second delay at end of alarm() so that it triggers only once every alarm time